# How to handle PUT request in Django RestFramework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update my data in 'VoterList' model by using PUT api, but i don't know which function should i use in my 'views.py' file to handle the coming PUT request because in PUT api, we use parameters from URL to pick the relevent entry from model for updation and then update it by using data received from PUT api.

model.py

```
class VoterList(models.Model):
    # id = models.IntegerField(auto_created= True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField( max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class FillVoterListSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = VoterList
        fields = ('id','name', 'email', 'mobile', 'city', 'type')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.pop("name", instance.name)
        instance.email = validated_data.pop("email", instance.email)
        instance.save()

        return  instance
```

I will manage the code for PUT in serializers by myself.

views.py

```
class UpdateVoter(APIView):

    serializer_class =  FillVoterListSerializers
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request,*args,**kwargs):

        isDataExist =  VoterList.objects.get(id=request.data.get('id'))

        if not isDataExist:
            return Response({"message":"No Voter exist with this id."})
        else:
            isDataUpdated =  self.serializer_class(isDataExist, request.data, partial=True)

            if isDataUpdated.is_valid():
                isDataUpdated.save()
                return Response({"message": "Voter updated."})
            else:
                return  Response({"message": "All fields are Mandatory."})
```

urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
  url('api/updateVoter/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', UpdateVoter.as_view(), name= "updateVoter")]
```

So what code should i write in my view.py to handle the PUT request.

Note: I want to tell you that i am preparing api for mobile applications, so please respond accordingly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You use the `put` method in the `ApiVew`. If you do a regular post with a particular variable sent with it you can find that in the `request` object and use that to differentiate where to send it (like your own put method).

Comment: @dan-klasson - Thanks for your response. But your response is an alternative of the question which i asked. I already tried my luck with the solution which you provided and it worked too. but I am looking for the way, if we go through PUT request.

Comment: See my first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the put() function in your view similar to the post() which you've used

```
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
     # Your code here
```

Refer the DRF docs : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/